# Doesn't NFSv4 have no_root_squash?

Tags: linux, centos, nfs

When I in `/etc/fstab` have

```
nas:/tank/nobackup  /mnt/nas       nfs     exec,nosuid,rw,bg,soft 0 0
```

then `mount -a; mount` gives

```
nas:/tank/nobackup on /mnt/nas type nfs (rw,nosuid,bg,soft,vers=4,addr=10.10.10.10,clientaddr=10.10.10.11)
```

but creating a file in the mount point gives permission denied.

If I add `no_root_squash` to `/etc/fstab` when I get

```
mount.nfs: an incorrect mount option was specified
```

**Question**

Isn't `no_root_squash` supported on NFSv4? And if not, then which is the recommended?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`no_root_squash` is a server side (export) option, not a client side option. It therefore doesn't go in `/etc/fstab`, nor can it be specified to `mount`.

If you think about it - why would you want a client to be able to decide "hey, I'll be root today, that'll be nice"?

http://linux.die.net/man/5/exports

I'd suggest though, that rather than setting `no_root_squash` instead you want to set `root=`, and designate some specific clients to act as `root`.